# XML files Exploration and Values execution

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

```
    <imgdir name="02380000">
    <imgdir name="info">
        <canvas name="icon" width="32" height="32">
            <vector name="origin" x="0" y="32"/>
        </canvas>
        <canvas name="iconRaw" width="27" height="38">
            <vector name="origin" x="0" y="38"/>
        </canvas>
        <int name="price" value="1"/>
        <int name="tradeBlock" value="1"/>
        <int name="bigSize" value="1"/>
        <int name="only" value="1"/>
        <int name="monsterBook" value="1"/>
        <int name="mob" value="100100"/>
    </imgdir>
    <imgdir name="spec">
        <int name="consumeOnPickup" value="1"/>
    </imgdir>
</imgdir>
```

hello everyone,im trying to get only 2 specific data rows but unfortunately it doesnt work out as i want would love to have some help ;3

this is my code

```
 public void ReadValue_FromXML()
    {
        //====================================
        string Path = FilePathString_box.Text;
        Path.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
        //====================================
        string ConnectionStringPath = "";
        MySqlConnection MySqlCon = new MySqlConnection();
        MySqlCon.ConnectionString = ConnectionStringPath;
        string Update_MonsterCardsData = " INSERT INTO monstercarddata (id,cardid,mobid)VALUES(@Rowid,@CardNumber,@mob);";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Path);
        int CountElements;


        var elements = doc.SelectNodes("//imgdir");

        foreach (XmlNode node in elements)
        {

            string MonsterCardIDx;
            string MobID;
            if (ReadNameAndValue(node, out MobID))
            {

                MonsterCardIDx = node.SelectSingleNode("./@name").InnerText;
                if (MonsterCardIDx != "0238.img")
                {
                    if (MobID != "" )
                    {

                        int Row = 1;
                        ElementCount_lebel.Text = Row.ToString();
                        int MonsterCard = Int32.Parse(MonsterCardIDx);
                        MySqlCommand MySqlComnd = new MySqlCommand(Update_MonsterCardsData, MySqlCon);
                        MySqlParameter MonsterCardID = new MySqlParameter("@CardNumber", MySqlDbType.Int32); 
                        MonsterCardID.Value = MonsterCard;
                        MySqlComnd.Parameters.Add(MonsterCardID);

                        MySqlParameter MonsterID = new MySqlParameter("@mob", MySqlDbType.Int32); 
                        MonsterID.Value = MobID;
                        MySqlComnd.Parameters.Add(MonsterID);
                        MySqlParameter RowID = new MySqlParameter("@Rowid", MySqlDbType.Int32); 
                        RowID.Value = Row;
                        MySqlComnd.Parameters.Add(RowID);

                        try
                        {
                            MySqlCon.Open();
                            MySqlComnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            MySqlCon.Close();
                            Row++;


                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

    private bool ReadNameAndValue(XmlNode parent, out string MobID)
    {

        MobID = "";

        var node = parent.SelectSingleNode("./imgdir");
        if (node == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            if (parent.SelectSingleNode("./int/name").InnerText == "mob")
            {
                MobID = parent.SelectSingleNode("./int/value").InnerText;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The output i get is `MonasterCard =02380000 and MobID=""`

but `mobID` should be `100100`

Comment: There is an error in the method ReadNameAndValue().  Can't help without seeing the xml.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE :**

Currently, your code only checks `name` attribute of the *first child `<int>`* element of `parent`, that's why it didn't find the target `<int name="mob" value="100100"/>`. I'd suggest to use XPath to find the target `<int>` by checking its `name` attribute value, like so :

```
var mobAttribute = parent.SelectSingleNode("./int[@name = 'mob']/@value");
if(mob != null)
{
    MobID = mobAttribute.Value;
}
```

---

**initial answer :**

You forgot to add `@` before attribute name to reference attribute using XPath expression :

```
if (parent.SelectSingleNode("./int/@name").InnerText == "mob")
{
    MobID = parent.SelectSingleNode("./int/@value").InnerText;
}
```

Without the `@` symbol, the expression is still valid but will reference child element `<name>`, for example, instead of attribute `name`. There is no such element, that's why you got empty for `MobID`.

Comment: i forgot to change it here ;\ but in the actually code it was like this and still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code in ReadNameAndValue method within try block with this one

```
var intNodes = node.SelectNodes("./int");
                foreach (var intNode in intNodes)
                {
                    if (((XmlElement) intNode).Attributes["name"].Value == "mob")
                    {
                        MobID = ((XmlElement) intNode).Attributes["value"].Value;
                    }
                }
```

In your case you need to read attributes, but not text inside nodes

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq.  You have a xml file where there are multiple tags "int" and you want only the one with the name = mob.  This is better handled with xml linq.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string xml =
                    "<imgdir name=\"02380000\">" +
                        "<imgdir name=\"info\">" +
                            "<canvas name=\"icon\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\">" +
                                "<vector name=\"origin\" x=\"0\" y=\"32\"/>" +
                            "</canvas>" +
                            "<canvas name=\"iconRaw\" width=\"27\" height=\"38\">" +
                                "<vector name=\"origin\" x=\"0\" y=\"38\"/>" +
                            "</canvas>" +
                            "<int name=\"price\" value=\"1\"/>" +
                            "<int name=\"tradeBlock\" value=\"1\"/>" +
                            "<int name=\"bigSize\" value=\"1\"/>" +
                            "<int name=\"only\" value=\"1\"/>" +
                            "<int name=\"monsterBook\" value=\"1\"/>" +
                            "<int name=\"mob\" value=\"100100\"/>" +
                        "</imgdir>" +
                        "<imgdir name=\"spec\">" +
                            "<int name=\"consumeOnPickup\" value=\"1\"/>" +
                        "</imgdir>" +
                    "</imgdir>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            foreach (XElement imgdir in doc.Elements("imgdir"))
            {
                string MobID = (string)imgdir.Descendants("int").ToList().Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "mob").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an observation, changing your code to...  MobID = (string)doc.Descendants("int").ToList().Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "mob").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("value"); ... (doc in place of imgdir) will eliminate the need for the foreach loop will it not?

Comment: I can't tell from XML provided if there is more than one parent element.  The original code is filtering for NOT "0238" which implies more than one parent.